# python unbound method again

Tags: python, class

This gets me into difficult time (sorry, i am still very new to python)
Thank you for any kind of help.

The error

> ```
> print Student.MostFrequent() TypeError: unbound method
> ```
>
> MostFrequent() must be called with
>   Student instance as first argument
>   (got nothing instead)

This Student.MostFrequent() is called all the way in the end (last line) and the def is last def in the class

EDITED - Naming convention

My long code

```
import csv
class Student:
    sports = []
    ftopics = []
    stopics = []
    choice_list = []
    choice_dict = {}
    def __init__(self, row):
       self.lname, self.fname, self.ID, self.gender, self.sport, self.movie, self.movieyr, self.country, self.ftopic, self.stopic = row
       self.sports.append(self.sport)
       self.ftopics.append(self.ftopic)
       self.stopics.append(self.stopic)
    def print_information(self):
       return (self.lname, self.fname, self.ID, self.gender)
    def print_first(self):
       return (self.lname, self.fname, self.sport)
    def print_second(self):
        return (self.lname, self.fname, self.movie, self.movieyr)
    def print_third(self):
        return (self.lname, self.fname, self.country)
    def print_fourth(self):
        return (self.lname, self.fname, self.ftopic, self.stopic)
    def most_frequent(self):
        for choice in self.choice_list:
                self.choice_dict[choice] = self.choice_dict.get(choice, 0) + 1
        self.mostFrequent = sorted([(v, k) for k, v in self.choice_dict.items()], reverse=True)
        print self.mostFrequent

reader = csv.reader(open('new_mondy_csc_data_revise.csv'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
header = tuple(reader.next())
print "%-17s|%-10s|%-6s|%s" %header[:4]
print "-" * 45
students = list(map(Student, reader)) # read all remaining lines
for student in students:
    print "%-17s|%-10s|%-6s|%3s" % student.print_information()

print "%-17s|%-10s|%s" %(header[0],header[1],header[4])
print "-" * 45
for student in students:
    print "%-17s|%-10s|%s" %student.print_first()

print "%-17s|%-10s|%-16s|%s" %(header[0],header[1],header[5],header[6])
print "-" * 45
for student in students:
    print "%-17s|%-10s|%-16s|%s" % student.print_second()

print "%-17s|%-10s|%s" %(header[0],header[1],header[7])
print "-" * 45
for student in students:
    print "%-17s|%-10s|%s" %student.print_third()

print "%-17s|%-10s|%-15s|%s" %(header[0],header[1],header[8],header[9])
print "-" * 45
for student in students:
    print "%-17s|%-10s|%-16s|%s" % student.print_fourth()

k = len(students)    
# Printing all sports that are specified by students
for s in set(Student.sports): # class attribute
    print s, Student.sports.count(s), round(((float(Student.sports.count(s)) / k) *100),1)

# Printing sports that are not picked 
allsports = ['Basketball','Football','Other','Baseball','Handball','Soccer','Volleyball','I do not like sport']
allsports.sort()
for s in set(allsports) - set(Student.sports):
    print s, 0, '0%'
Student.choice_list = Student.sports
X = Student()
X.most_frequent()

#class Search(Student):
#    def __init__(self):
#        Student.__init__
```

Answer (score 7):

use `Student().MostFrequent()`

**edit**:

beware that you use class attributes and this is dangerous. here an example:

```
>>> class Person:
...  name = None
...  hobbies = []
...  def __init__(self, name):
...   self.name = name
... 
>>> a = Person('marco')
>>> b = Person('francesco')
>>> a.hobbies.append('football')
>>> b.hobbies
['football']
>>> a.name
'marco'
>>> b.name
'francesco'
>>> a.name = 'mario'
>>> b.name
'francesco'
>>> a.name
'mario'
>>>
```

as you can see i modify marco's hobbies and francesco's hobbies are modified consequentially.

Comment: does this work with a constructor like: def __init__(self, row)?

Comment: and how steve said remove the mostFrequent argument from the method definition, but the error you got is related to the fact that you don't instance the class

Comment: @The MYYN: no. maybe i hastily answer the question but he gets that error because he calls a method over a class and not an object. to call a method over a class there are `classmethod` and `staticmethod` decorators. see the doc about their use.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed for my django validator on a field where I didn't want to create an instance of the validator class but `validators = [ValidatorClass().function_name]` was what I needed to do!

Answer (score 7):

**first** read [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) on naming conventions:

> Method Names and Instance Variables

```
  Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by
  underscores as necessary to improve readability.
```

**second** you are calling `mostFrequest` on the class `Student`, not an instance of it. Use the method on an instance instead:

```
student = Student(row)
student.MostFrequent()
```

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want is to define `most_frequent` as a [`classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod):

```
@classmethod
def most_frequent(cls):
    for choice in cls.choice_list:
        cls.choice_dict[choice] = cls.choice_dict.get(choice, 0) + 1
    cls.mostFrequent = sorted([(v, k) for k, v in cls.choice_dict.items()], reverse=True)
    return cls.mostFrequent
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend making function names lower case only.

The error you get results from the usage of `MostFrequent` as a static method. For this to work, you need to explicitly pass an instance of `Student` as first argument.

If called directly on an instance of `Student`, the instance will implicitly be passed as first argument.

Consider using the `staticmethod` decorator for static usage of functions.

Answer (score 0):

You only rarely call methods on a  class definition (`Student`)

Almost always, you create an instance of the class

```
someStudent = Student(someRow)
```

Then you call the method on the instance ("object"), `someStudent`.

```
someStudent.MostFrequent()
```

Answer (score 0):

Student.MostFrequent means You're trying to use static method, not instance method. So You must first create instance by calling Student() and then call MostFrequent() on it.

P.S.: If this is not part of some arcane project, I urge you to follow PEP 8 and use most_frequent as method name.

Answer (score -1):

in your class def, the method definition

```
def MostFrequent(self,mostFrequent):
```

has the extra variable *mostFrequent* that you probably don't want there. Try changing to :

```
def MostFrequent(self):
```

Comment: i guess in this case this would complain about wrong number of arguments, or not?

Comment: always nice to see a CS grad in a hissy fit